# Qt 5.2.1 QFileDialog GDB strange behaviour

Tags: qt, gdb, qt5, qfiledialog, qt5.2

I'm using Qt 5.2.1 MinGW 32bit on a Windows 7 machine with gdb from the MinGW 4.8.
There is a strange behaviour when i try to singlestep through the code.

```
QFileDialog open;
open.setDefaultSuffix("tst");
QString fileName=open.getSaveFileName(this,tr("New File"),"",tr("Test File (*.tst)"));
if(fileName!="")
{
...
```

Im setting a breakpoint at the 1st Line.
Singlestepping works until the 3rd Line, than, after choosing a file, gdb says:

> Cannot insert breakpoint -1217.
>   Error accessing memory address 0x7219cd30: Input/output error.

When i set a Breakpoint insede the if or after, the Debugger stops at the Breakpoint, but when i try to singlestep after the stop, the same error occurs.

When i set the FileName directly like:

```
QFileDialog open;
open.setDefaultSuffix("tst");
QString fileName="D:\path\to\File.tst";
if(fileName!="")
{
...
```

Singlestepping works without any problems.

The Code above runs without any problem, the problem only occurs when i try to singlestep.

Does anyone knows the problem, or a suitable workaround?

Comment: The problem is probably in `open.getSaveFileName()` that opens a modal dialog that blocks the execution to the next line `if(fileName!="")...`. I would put a breakpoint on line four too to stop when a file is selected.

Comment: I tried that. But when I place a breakpoint at Line 4 (or later, i'm doing a lot of things in the if) the same error occurs. @vahancho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QFileDialog::getSaveFileName()` is a static function, but you call it like a member method. 
I'm only guessing, but probably the way you are calling a static member via an object confuses your debugging environment - the compiler should generate valid code though, so running over your code will work.

BTW, setDefaultSuffix will not work as expected, as getSaveFileName is a static member and will not look at your QFileDialog object.